# How to call a Bootstrap pop-up Model from JS function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

I want to call a bootstrap Pop-Up Model from JS function with the values which are in my Function if the user press update then back to JS function and update the values if press cancels then nothing.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("BulkUpdate", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="container col-md-12">
    <table id="myTable" class="cell-border compact hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.First().Id)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.First().TagName)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.First().TagCategory)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.First().TagValue)</th>
                <th> Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].Id)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Id)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].TagName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model[i].TagCategory)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => Model[i].TagValue, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "TagVaule_" + Model[i].Id, @class = "form-control" } })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="UpdateRow(@Model[i].Id)">Update</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <button onclick="Cancel()">cancel</button>
                <button onclick="Confirm()">confirm</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Bulk Update" class="btn btn-secondary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

}
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').DataTable();
        });
    </script>


    <script>
        debugger;
            function UpdateRow(id)
            {
                var tagvalue = $("#TagVaule_" + id).val();
                DisplayModal();
            }

            function DisplayModal()
            {
                $("#myModal").modal('show')
            }

            function Cancel()
            {
                $("#myModal").modal('hide')
            }

            function Confirm()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Update","Home")',
                    data: {
                        id: id,
                        value: tagvalue
                    },
                });
                $("#myModal").modal('hide')
            }

    </script>
}
```

Currently I using built in confirm function but istead of this confirm function i want to call bootstrap model and want to show tagvalue  and the old value against that tagvalue on pop-up model then if user press update i want to submit it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to just do what needs to be done when confirm is clicked on the modal

javascript:

```
var bootStrapId=0;
var tagvalue = 0
function UpdateRow(id)
{
    tagvalue=$("#TagVaule_" + id).val();
    bootStrapId=id;
    DisplayModal();
}

function DisplayModal()
{
    $("#myModal").modal('show')
}

function Cancel()
{
    $("#myModal").modal('hide')
}

function Confirm()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Update","Home")',
        data: {
            id: bootStrapID,
            value: tagvalue
        },
    });
    $("#myModal").modal('hide')
}
```

html:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <button onclick="Cancel()">cancel</button>
        <button onclick="Confirm()">confirm</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi sir, tried your code but nothing is happing and there is no error in console as well can you please help me more? And I am updating the code in question

Comment: I tried but UpdateRow() click model is not visible?

Comment: it works fine here.... https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GA4LYUC22UY8